# I want to add the listbox scroll fade effect in my app - how?

Tags: gtk, vala

I am referring to the effect eg. the session indicator has or the keyboard language adder has. I'd prefer it with the responsiveness the session listbox has.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common way a designer can do this is by applying on an upper layer a semitransparent png image or gradient with fading transparency from 1 to 0 and white color. Another option is a gtk box shadow with white color.

edit: I believe this is what are you looking for:

<kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>shft</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>
[image: dev tool]

The style is into gtk-widgets.css, line 3840

```
popover undershoot.top {
background:
    linear-gradient(
        @bg_color 0%,
        alpha(@bg_color, 0) 50%
    );}
```

[image: gtk-widgets.css]

Comment: Sure, but is this how it's done properly by elemenetary? I mean, I examined the source code of the session indicator but I couldn't find anything like it.

Comment: It is more like a style than the code and probably you can find this not into session indicator code but in elementary os theme. Look at my answer again

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: that is super helpful! However for me `@bg_color` didn't work, but `@theme_bg_color` did. It may be because i'm not on elementary OS, but just using plain gtk.

Comment: It is just a variable name that for sure could be different depending on the gtk theme. It can be safely replaced with any hexadecimal color value like `#ffffff` or `#000` or even web colors like  `red`, or `white` for example.

Answer (score 0):

[Gtk.ScrolledWindow](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.ScrolledWindow.html) is what you're looking for. It comes with everything you see in the screenshot you added: the vertical scroll bar to the right, the blue hue animations when reaching the top or the bottom of the list...

Basically, I suggest creating a [Gtk.ListBox](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.ListBox.html), populate it with whatever widgets you might need, and then add it to a Gtk.ScrolledWindow. Then, add the Gtk.ScrollerWindow to whatever container you need it to appear into. It will most likely inherit the container's width and height, and try to display the ListBox's contents as pretty as possible. Using a ListBox will also allow you to easily implement filtering of it's contents, if needed.  I can supply an example [here](https://github.com/popvladaurel/torrential-remote/blob/75d092cc2d7e1883f77115ffd9bc9cd40a14b748/src/Main/Window.vala#L13) if you're interested.

This a screenshot of the implementation linked above:
[image]

Comment: That was not what I was looking for. I was looking for the fading, not the blue light.